# MySQL table auto creation is not working in Loopback node API framework after installing MySQL connectors

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

1.I have created a demo application in loopback using "lb demo" command.

2.Then, successfully installed MySQL connectors using "npm install loopback-connector-mysql --save" this command.

3.Then create user model with firstName and lastName properties.

4. Trying to post data using GUI explorer on "http://localhost:3000/explorer/" but it throws "TABLE NOT EXIST ERROR".

or can we need to manually create MySQL tables.?

Please suggest any solution. I tried a lot for this but not able to resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your steps you never did try to auto create them.

To invoke automigrate try creating `server/bin/automigrate.js` with the following code, then run `node server/bin/automigrate` in your project directory

```
var server = require('./server');
var ds = server.dataSources.MYDATASOURCE;
var lbTables = ['myUserModel', 'anotherModelIWantToCreate'];
ds.automigrate(lbTables, function(er) {
  if (er) throw er;
  console.log('Loopback tables [' - lbTables - '] created in ', ds.adapter.name);
  ds.disconnect();
});
```

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html

> Warning: Auto-migration will drop an existing table if its name
>   matches a model name. When tables with data exist, use auto-update to
>   avoid data loss.

Comment: Thanks man, its work for me :)
refer this loopback latest doc link.
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html